# sending data through wifi using get by IP from an android cell phone to arduino+esp8266

Tags: android, arduino, esp8266

I am using IP to transfer data from  android to arduino, hopefully I am able to establish the connection with arduino+esp8266 wifi module by choosing its name in the wifi lists in setting since its working as access point. Also through any browser I can send data to the IP by only writing this "192.168.4.1:80?pin=13". However I have a problem with android which is the get not transmitting the request because of its not received by the arduino.

Here is my code, I have also included internet permission in android manifest. What is wrong with it?

```
final Button    image=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            image.setText("making change");
            String urlGET = "http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=13";
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(urlGET);
            // if you are having some headers in your URL uncomment below line 
            //getMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/form-data");
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String responseBody = null;

                if (entity != null) {
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                  //here you get response returned from your server
                    Log.e("response = ", responseBody);

                    // response.getEntity().consumeContent();

                }
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                 // do whatever you want to do with your json reponse data

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });

}


    }
```

Comment: You should paste in your code without tabs (replace them with 4 spaces). Then use Ctrl+K on the whole block to indent it four spaces to get the code setup.

Answer (score 2):

1) I think, you already added this permission to manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

2) Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    // if you perform a networking operation in the main thread
    // you must add these lines.
    // OR (I prefer) you can do asynchronously.

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

3) Call doTest2() method at button.onclick.
I changed Apache HttpClient to  java.net.HttpURLConnection.

[please look this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153434/1523490)

```
private void doTest2() {
    String urlGET = "http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=13";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlGET);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int data = isr.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            sb.append(current);
            data = isr.read();
        }

        System.out.print(sb.toString());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.